# layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind, at) not getting called

Tags: ios, swift

My collectionview has an array of data and I also need to dynamically add divider according to the creation date of the data. I register `forCell` for data and `forSupplementaryView` for divider. In the custom `UICollectionViewLayout`'s `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)`, I return `[attributes]` of cells and supplementary views that intersect with `rect`.

The issue is `layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath)` gets called but never does `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)`. Why is it never called? How does it know the `attributes` for the divider at each `IndexPath`?